# Send key from C# to interrupt Fortran process

Tags: c#, fortran, interop, intel-fortran

I need to communicate with a command line Fortran app using a c# wrapper. The Fortran process is started using the following c# code.

```
var process = new Process();

process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToFortranExe)
{
  WorkingDirectory = directory,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardError = true,
  RedirectStandardInput = true,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true
}; 

...
//listen for prompts from the Fortran program 
//and send replies using standardInput as follows
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(data);
```

When the Fortran program is waiting for user input on the command line I can successfully send messages using the above code.

Now here is the problem. The Fortran program uses long running analysis loops which can be interrupted by sending keys such as `Esq` or `Q`. I've been told this interrupt feature is implemented in the Fortran code using the Intel Fortran command [PEEKCHARQQ](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/512026). When I try and trigger these keys from c# using StandardInput they are ignored by the Fortran program. To send these interrupt signals I use:

```
char key = 'q'
process.StandardInput.Write(key);
//Note that StandardInput.AutoFlush==true
```

I've also tried SendMessage via pinvoke, but again no luck so far:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

 private const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
 private const UInt32 WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

 public static void SendKey(Process process, char key)
 {
     var keyCode = (IntPtr)key;
     var hWnd = process.Handle;

     SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, IntPtr.Zero);
     SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, keyCode, IntPtr.Zero);
 }
```

So the question is: Are there any other ways to place keys into the keyboard buffer such that they might be picked up PEEKCHARQQ in the Fortran process? Or anything else that I might be missing here?

**Update 1:**

I've also tried WriteConsoleInput, but I don't think I have the right handle:

```
var keyCode = (short)key;
var hWnd = process.Handle;

INPUT_RECORD[] lpBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[1];

lpBuffer[0].KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = keyCode;

int nLength = lpBuffer.Length;
int lpNumberOfEventsWritten;

if (!WriteConsoleInput(
   hWnd,
   lpBuffer,
   nLength,
   out lpNumberOfEventsWritten))
{
   //this results error code 6: Invalid handle
   Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", GetLastError());
}
```

Comment: I suspect you need to use the WriteConsoleInput Win32 API, using the standard input handle that you have as the handle for the console input buffer.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it out but it gives a handle error. Please see the updated example code above. Any idea where to get the console handle from for the target process?

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the console input buffer for the child process using a handle to the [`CONIN$`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) device with the WriteConsoleInput API.

Two Fortran programs below to demonstrate.   The program for the child process:

```
PROGRAM peek_a_boo
  USE IFCORE
  IMPLICIT NONE

  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: fmt = "('Press any key!')"

  PRINT fmt
  DO WHILE (.NOT. PEEKCHARQQ())
    CALL SLEEPQQ(2000)
    PRINT fmt
  END DO
END PROGRAM peek_a_boo
```

The program that shows the Windows API calls.  You can translate this to whichever language floats your boat.

```
PROGRAM peek_parent
  USE IFWIN
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(BOOL) :: api_result
  INTEGER(HANDLE) :: console_input
  TYPE(T_STARTUPINFO) :: startup_info
  TYPE(T_PROCESS_INFORMATION) :: process_info
  TYPE(T_INPUT_RECORD) :: input_record
  INTEGER(DWORD) :: events_written
  INTEGER(DWORD) :: wait_event

  ! Create the child process.
  CALL ZeroMemory(LOC(startup_info), SIZEOF(startup_info))
  startup_info%cb = SIZEOF(startup_info)

  api_result = CreateProcess( &
      'peek_a_boo.exe',  &
      NULL,  &      ! command line.
      NULL,  &      ! process security attributes.
      NULL,  &      ! thread security attributes.
      .FALSE.,  &   ! inherit handles.
      0_DWORD,  &
      NULL,  &      ! environment.
      NULL,  &      ! current directory.
      startup_info,  &
      process_info )

  IF (api_result == 0) THEN
    ERROR STOP 'Couldn''t start it :('
  END IF

  api_result = CloseHandle(process_info%hThread)

  ! Let the child run for a bit.
  CALL SLEEPQQ(5000)

  ! Get a handle to our console input buffer.
  console_input = CreateFile(  &
      'CONIN$',  &
      GENERIC_WRITE,  &
      IANY([FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE]),  &
      NULL,  &       ! security attrs
      OPEN_EXISTING,  &
      0_DWORD,  &    ! attributes
      NULL )         ! template file
  IF (console_input == 0) THEN
    ERROR STOP 'Couldn''t open it :('
  END IF

  ! Poke something into the buffer.
  input_record%EventType = KEY_EVENT
  input_record%KeyEvent%bKeyDown = .TRUE.
  input_record%KeyEvent%wRepeatCount = 1
  input_record%KeyEvent%wVirtualKeyCode = INT(Z'51', WORD)
  input_record%KeyEvent%wVirtualScanCode = INT(Z'51', WORD)
  input_record%KeyEvent%AsciiChar = 'Q'
  input_record%KeyEvent%dwControlKeyState = 0
  api_result = WriteConsoleInput(  &
      console_input,  &
      input_record,  &
      1,  &
      LOC(events_written) )

  ! Wait for the child to terminate.
  wait_event = WaitForSingleObject(process_info%hProcess, INFINITE)
  api_result = CloseHandle(console_input)
  api_result = CloseHandle(process_info%hProcess)
END PROGRAM peek_parent
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed example, However, I don't see how the CreateFile command in your code creates a link with a specific child process. If there were multiple instances of peek_a_boo, would they all receive the poked message using this approach?

Comment: In the above case, the child is created in the same console as the parent, hence it has the same console input buffer.  For multiple children in multiple consoles you may need to set the console up for each child process, separately, before starting the child.  Note that normally from the child's point of view the standard input handle is also a handle to the input buffer for the console that the child is attached to, unless that standard input handle has been redirected (and I think you are redirecting it).